# Conversion of PHP/MySQL Page to .jpg and Inserting image to MySQL field at another domain?

Tags: php, mysql, database, jpeg

I'm working on a project related to Online Management Information System for Hospitals with core php and mysql. Most components I've completed but where I'm stuck is probably not the problem with coding its probably not having the Idea how to do it; What I want to do is; when the management prepares the report of a patient it is published and remains entirely only for the management and doctors to view and review and verification purposes etc after which the site admin PUBLISHES it by click of command button. With this function the entire report which is in the form of HTML/PHP page & MySQL at the back-end is converted to a .jpg format and this image is supposed to be inserted to a MySQL database at another URL. Its simple as that and I don't know how to do it? Any help would be appreciated please! Thanks!

Comment: And have you done any research on this? Maybe topics like saving a rendered webpage as an image?  Saving an image to a database?

Comment: Yea! Thanks! Any code snippet reflecting a merger of both I mean saving a rendered webpage to a directory and inserting only the URL in the database field would get me going. Since the site admin would have to publish many reports per day so I want to reduce clicking. Any  easy way?

Comment: "Any easy way?"  Hire someone.  Other than that, do your own research, write your own code, and _then_ when you get stuck on something _specific_, ask a question that that includes the relevant code and describes the problem _in detail_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can parse html & create pdf/jpg image of site using library as http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ or https://github.com/spatie/browsershot using headless chrome

Comment: Thanks! I prefer to write my own code, third part tools/plugins are the options last on list.

Comment: so if you don;t want to use those libraries you have to write own html parser in html and then save resutls as image, if you don't want to use external libraries you could write own small headless chrome library, it should be easiest solution for screenshotting webpage